# java.lang.RuntimeException in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I cannot print simple hello world script in kotlin. I connected my mobile phone. Although I enabled usb debugging, I got this error :

java.lang.RuntimeException

here is my code:

`fun main() { println("hellooo") }`

Answer (score 1):

**You can Use** `Log` **like this**. (It's quit good in android)

```
Log.d("TAG", "hellooo")
Log.i("TAG", "hellooo")
Log.w("TAG", "hellooo")
Log.e("TAG", "hellooo")
```

But you also can use `print` and `println` in kotlin

```
print("hellooo")
println("hellooo")
```

Check for is there any other error.